# ES2015 templates not properly formatted in Emacs JavaScript mode

Tags: javascript, emacs

Right now it looks totally ugly if I use ES2015 templates:

```
 let template =`<div data-value="${text}"
 class="label label-success">
     ${text}
     <span data-nr="${nr}" 
 class="background-switch glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
 style="border-radius:50%;margin-left: 2px; padding: 3px;"
 aria-hidden="true">
    </span>
    </div>`;
```

Is there a way to disable the default indent settings for a certain region ? Or is there any other way to properly format ES6 templates ?

Comment: Have you tried different major modes at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=browse;oldid=JavaScript;id=CategoryJavaScript?